# How to get access to duplicate rownames in shiny in R

Tags: r, shiny

I am facing a common problem in environmental science. There often dealing with a
rock horizon or soil horizon to compare the different horizon`s by a
distinct element concentration.

For an shiny app, I got no clue how to access to the row of a column. Because the
rows are non unique! Suppose a, profil is divided by several horizon`s. The presented
example might show you this:

```
####################################################
```

```
 library (shiny)
    library(shinyWidgets)
    library(dplyr)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(viridis)
    library(hrbrthemes)
    library(rio)
    ######################################################
    { set.seed(1234)
       
      A = tibble (
    Horizon = ("Horizon A"),
    Depth     = seq(0, 2.6, 0.2),
    Element_1 =  abs(round(rnorm(14), 2)),
    Element_2 =  abs(round(rnorm(14), 2)),
    Element_3 =  abs(round(rnorm(14), 2))
    ); A
    
     B = tibble (
    Horizon = ("Horizon B"),
    Depth     = seq(2.8, 43.8, 0.33),
    Element_1 =  abs(round(rnorm(125), 2)),
    Element_2 =  abs(round(rnorm(125), 2)),
    Element_3 =  abs(round(rnorm(125), 2))
    ); B
     
     C = tibble (
    Horizon = ("Horizon C"),
    Depth     = seq(44, 50, 0.6),
    Element_1 =  abs(round(rnorm(11), 2)),
    Element_2 =  abs(round(rnorm(11), 2)),
    Element_3 =  abs(round(rnorm(11), 2))
    ); C
     
     Analyse = rbind (A, B, C); Analyse 
     
    }
```

Now I would like to display a boxplot like this:

```
    ## single element & single horizon
      Analyse%>%
      pivot_longer(
        cols = Element_1: Element_3,
        names_to = "Element",
        values_to = "Values")%>%
      filter(Horizon == "Horizon B" & Element == "Element_3")%>%
      ggplot(aes(x= "", y= Values)) +  
      geom_boxplot(notch = TRUE, color = "#e9ecef", fill="#69b3a2", outlier.colour = "red", width = 0.6)+
      stat_summary(fun = "mean", color = "black", shape = 8) +
      geom_jitter(alpha = 0.8, width = 0.2, height = 0, color = "orange") +
      #facet_wrap( ~ Element, scales = 'free_y', nrow = 1)+
      labs(title = "Boxplot",
           subtitle = "Black stars: mean value
    Red dots: outlier",
           caption = "Horizont C",
           tag = "")+
      theme_ipsum() +
      theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
            axis.text.x=element_blank(),
            axis.ticks.x=element_blank())+
      theme(plot.title = element_text(size=15))
    
    # compare one element within all horizon`s`
    Analyse%>%
      ggplot(aes(x= "", y= Element_2)) +  
      geom_boxplot(notch = TRUE, color = "#e9ecef", fill="#69b3a2", outlier.colour = "red", width = 0.6)+
      stat_summary(fun = "mean", color = "black", shape = 8) +
      geom_jitter(alpha = 0.8, width = 0.2, height = 0, color = "orange") +
      facet_wrap( ~ Horizon, scales = 'free_y', nrow = 1)+
      labs(title = "Boxplot",
           subtitle = "Black stars: mean value
    Red dots: outlier",
           caption = "",
           tag = "")+
      theme_ipsum() +
      theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
            axis.text.x=element_blank(),
            axis.ticks.x=element_blank())+
      theme(plot.title = element_text(size=15))
```

The next step is to implement such plots in shiny.The following script will show you:

```
    ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(title = h4(" Shiny App", align = "center")),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      pickerInput(
        inputId = "lith",
        label = "Select Horizon",
        choices = unique(Analyse$Horizon),
          #list(
          #"Horizon" = c("Horizon A", "Horizon B", "Horizon C")),
        selected = NULL,
        multiple = TRUE),
      options =  list("max-options" = 3,
                      "max-options-text" = "No more!"),
      br(),
        pickerInput(
        inputId = "datatable",
        label = "Select Element",
        choices = colnames(Analyse [3:5]),
        multiple = TRUE,
        options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)
      ),
      textOutput(outputId = "res_classic")),
    
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(type = "tab",
                  tabPanel("Boxplot", plotOutput("box")))
      
    ))
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # The boxplot
  output$box = renderPlot({
    
         if (length(input$lith) == 0) return(Analyse)
         Analyse %>% dplyr::select(!!!input$lith)
         rownames = FALSE
    
    ggplot(Analyse, aes(x= "", y=.data[[input$datatable]]))+
      geom_boxplot(notch = TRUE, color = "#e9ecef", fill="#69b3a2", outlier.colour = "red", width = 0.6)+
      stat_summary(fun = "mean", color = "black", shape = 8) +
      geom_jitter(alpha = 0.8, width = 0.2, height = 0, color = "orange") +
      facet_wrap(~get(input$lith), scales = 'free_y', nrow = 1) +
           labs(title = "Boxplot",
           subtitle = "Black stars: mean value
Red dots: outlier",
           caption = "",
           tag = "")+
      theme_ipsum() +
      theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
            axis.text.x=element_blank(),
            axis.ticks.x=element_blank())+
      theme(plot.title = element_text(size=15))
    
  }, res = 96, height = 600, width = 900 )
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

My problems are :
It is there a way to get the same plots in shiny? In any case connecting
the UI with the server function, I`ll get the Error in :  Can't subset columns that don't exist. x Column` Horizon A` doesn't exist.

Which is true, because duplicate rownames are not allowed in R!

Is there another way to get access to the column "Horizon", to get the plots in shiny?

Summarize: I want display a single boxplot with one (selected) element and one horizon.
Adding per click another element within the same horizon.

Is that even possible in shiny?

Thanks for your support and help!

Comment: Yes, this can be done.  However, I feel you have at least two features of your data and your code that aren't helping you.  First, your dataset is not [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) because some of your column names (eg `Element_1`) contain information.  I suggest converting to long format before you try to plot because `gplot`, like other elements of the tidyverse is designed to work with tidy data.

Comment: Second, you are handling the interface between the character variables provided by Shiny's UI and the non-standard evaluation [NSE](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) of the tidyverse suboptimally.  (One side effect of using tidy data is that you will have much less issue with NSE because most (if not all) of the interface with Shiny's inputs will be based on data values rather than column names.

Comment: Hej, thanks for your fast response! I``m not sure what you mean with your second comment. May I ask you to provide more information. I already create a long version, however, shiny got no access to the data. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Can't install all your libraries at the moment, but does this make the trick?

```
  # The boxplot
  output$box = renderPlot({
    ## here comes the changes
    req(input$lith, input$datatable)
    
    if (length(input$lith) == 0) return(Analyse)
    Analyse <- Analyse %>% filter(Horizon == input$lith)
    
    ### end of changes
    ggplot(Analyse, aes(x= "", y=.data[[input$datatable]]))+
      geom_boxplot(notch = TRUE, color = "#e9ecef", fill="#69b3a2", outlier.colour = "red", width = 0.6)+
      stat_summary(fun = "mean", color = "black", shape = 8) +
      geom_jitter(alpha = 0.8, width = 0.2, height = 0, color = "orange") +
      facet_wrap(~get(input$lith), scales = 'free_y', nrow = 1) +
      labs(title = "Boxplot",
           subtitle = "Black stars: mean value ; Red dots: outlier",
           caption = "",
           tag = "")+
      theme_ipsum() +
      theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
            axis.text.x=element_blank(),
            axis.ticks.x=element_blank())+
      theme(plot.title = element_text(size=15))
    
  }, res = 96, height = 600, width = 900 )
```

Comment: Too bad, your suggested solution did not work. When executing the code, the message appears that the horizon was not found. The problem persists. I can't get access to the column with the horizon names. Question: Would a conversion to the long format help?  My guess is that the filter before the plot is not working? Am I right?